# how to get the value of html element on the same page using django/jinja

Tags: python, html, django, scripting, jinja2

i am writing code for django project and my html code is like,

```
Course <select name="Courses" value="Courses" id="Courses">
        <option value="MCA" selected>MCA</option>
    </select>
        
Year/Pattern <select name="pattern" value="Courses" id="pattern">
        <option value="newPattern" selected>New-Pattern</option>
        <option value="oldPattern" selected>Old-Pattern</option>
    </select>
```

and here i wanted to get the value as MCA from the option element and then compare with the database value, on the same page, so how can I write jinja code for this...?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have achieved what you are asking for. If you save `Courses` types in a `tuple` in your `models.py` for example:

```
class Course(models.Model) :
    Courses_Types = (
        ('MCA' , 'mca'),
        ('AAAA' , 'aaa'),
        ('BBBB' , 'bbb'),
    )
    course_type = models.CharField(max_length = 50 ,null = True,choices=Courses_Types)
```

And then in `views.py`:

```
def course_create(request) :
    if request.method == "POST":
        course_type_= request.POST.get('course_type ',False)
        myobj = Course(course_type= course_type_)

        myobj.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Item was created successfully!')
        print("POST in create")
        return redirect('your url')
    elif request.method == "GET":
        print("Get in Create")
        return render(request, 'AddItem.html')
```

And finally in `AddItem.html`:

```
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-25">
                            <label for="COURSE">course</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-75">
                            <select id="COURSE" name="course_type">
                                    <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
                                    <option value="AAAA">aaa</option>
                                    <option value="BBBB">bbb</option>

                            </select>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

And actually, there is no need to use jinja in this case. If you need more help feel free to comment.